# How to be notified of the Minimize button being pressed in an OSX Window?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics

*N.B.:* this relates to private (SPI) functions of the CoreGraphicServices framework.

I am currently running a CGSConnection to the Windowserver as the UniversalController (with the Dock killed), and would like to know how I can be notified that a CGSWindow has had the yellow minimize blob clicked.

Is there a notification event that I can watch for with CGSRegisterConnectionNotifyProc?

Perhaps the answer lies in HIToolbox? Any experienced CGS hackers out there have an idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

NSWindow has this method:

```
- (BOOL)windowShouldZoom:(NSWindow *) toFrame:(NSRect)proposedFrame
```

method that you can implement.

Or maybe i don't understand your question...

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for:) To put it in simple terms, this is deep deep system-level stuff.

Comment: You could always implement it, set a breakpoint inside your implementation, and follow the crumbs in the stack to see how you ultimately got there.

Answer (score 0):

[CGSGetWindowEventMask](http://code.google.com/p/undocumented-goodness/source/browse/trunk/CoreGraphics/CGSPrivate.h) or [CGSGetWindowGeometry](http://lipidity.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2006/11/coregraphicsservices.h) is my best guess but I've never tried my hand at it